# no me detecta la funcion --abs-- de la libreria --math.h--

Tags: c++

¿me pueden explicar por que no me detecta la fincion abs?,pues cuando lo ejecuto me sale un mensaje diciendo

**error: 'abs' not declared in this scope**

nota: uso el compilador codeblocks 13.12

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float a,b,c,d,e = 0,f,x,y;
    cout<<"numero de vertices : ";
    cin>>f;

    cin>>a>>b;
    x = a;
    y = b;

    for(int i = 0; i < f; i++){
        cin>>c>>d;
        x = x - c;
        y = y - d;
        x = abs(x);
        y = abs(y);
        e = e + sqrt(x*x + y*y);
        x = c;  // un arreglo en el codigo
        y = d;  // un arreglo en el codigo
    }
    x = x - a;
    y = y - b;
    x = abs(x);
    y = abs(y);
    e = e + sqrt(x*x+ y*y);

    cout<<e;
}
```

nota :el codigo es para resolver este ejercicio.

--Polígono--
Haz un programa que lee una secuencia de puntos 2D (pares de reales) que representan un polígono (el último punto de la secuencia es igual que el primero), y determina la longitud de su perímetro.

fuente
http://minidosis.org

Comment: por cierto, ¿haz intentado `#include<cmath>`? que es parte de c++. `<math.h>` es parte de las librerías de c. (sin ++)

Comment: @rnd use `cmath` en vez de `math.h` y me funciono!!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remplaza

```
#include<math.h>
```

por

```
#include<cmath>
```

`math.h` pertenece al estándar [c](/questions/tagged/c), debes utilizar las librerias del estándar de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Answer (score 2):

A mi me ha funcionado perfectamente una vez corregidos los errores señalados por [rnd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/25/rnd) y recordados por [Camilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10924/2742).

Puedes [[verlo aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LvZ6kdmMZfefwode).

---

Otros detalles a tener en cuenta:

#### Tipos de librerías

Las cabeceras de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no tienen extensión de archivo: `<iostream>`, `<vector>`, `<string>`, etc... excepto las cabeceras que existen por compatibilidad con [c](/questions/tagged/c): `<math.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, etc...

La mayoría de cabeceras de `C` disponen de una versión *portada* a `C++` a la que se le ha quitado la extensión, se les ha añadido el prefijo "c" (por ejemplo `<cmath>`, `<cstdint>`) y han sido adaptadas a `C++`. Si estás trabajando con `C++` deberías usar estas últimas no las de `C`.

#### Entender los errores

No se que compilador habrás usado, pero el código...

```
include<iostream>
include<math.h>
```

... no compila en ninguno de los compiladores de `C++` que yo conozco, muestra varios errores pero el **primero** que me da compilando en GCC es:

> ```
> prog.cc:1:1: error: 'include' does not name a type
>  include<iostream>
>  ^~~~~~~
> ```

Después ya informa de los errores de no encontrar `abs`. A la hora de corregir errores intenta seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. **Corrige de primer a último error**: No lo hagas en orden inverso pues en bastantes ocasiones errores posteriores son consecuencia de errores previos, así pues si tienes un error en la línea 50 y otro en la línea 2, empieza por el de la línea 2.
2. **El compilador no suele ser amigable con el humano**: A veces los textos de error son confusos, pero con un poco de experiencia los entenderás; si has de buscar solución a un error que no entiendes busca dicho error en internet explícitamente omitiendo cualquier referencia a tu código local (nombres de variables o funciones), por ejemplo veo que [otras personas](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22include+does+not+name+a+type%22#q=c%2B%2B+%22include+does+not+name+a+type%22) han tenido tu problema en [Codeblocks](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=21151.0).
3. **Si tras buscar no encuentras, pregunta BIEN**: A parte del código que te da problemas, debes también añadir los errores que te muestra tu compilador.

Answer (score 0):

Ya te han dado la respuesta, para incluír una librería usa #, sólo con eso debería funcionarte, pero no está por demás que cambies math.h por cmath (son lo mismo pero la segunda es de c++).

Comment: el motivo de el porque no aparece el `#` es por un error de copiar/pegar y si. cambiar `math.h` por `cmath` ha hecho que me funcione el programa